# If I don't pick up the heart container while leaving a dungeon, can I still get it?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

In Breath of the Wild, when a dungeon is over you cannot get back into it and go pick it back up.

So if you skip the heart container for some reason, and then want to go back and get it, is there any way? Or are you stuck with one less heart for the rest of the game?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [this post](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/189707-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/75155582),  if you miss a heart container after completing a dungeon, the container will appear outside the dungeon entrance for you to teleport back to.

> No, it will appear outside of the dungeon when you teleport back to it.

If you look at the link, all 3 posters agreed that this is what happens.

I also found [one other post](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/189707-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/75109278?page=1) where someone mentioned this as well.

Comment: "look at the Link" ;-)